# How 2 methods in different class use method dependency in testNG

Tags: testng

I wanted to access test method from class a and b

```
Class a{
@Test(dependsOnMethods="verifyElementsOnProfileScreen",alwaysRun = true)
    public void verifyMySelfProfileVisibility(){}
}

class b
@Test(dependsOnMethods="testdemo",alwaysRun = true)
    public void verifyMySelfProfileVisibility(){}
```

Comment: can you help me with some more info what is required..

Comment: Actually I have two testNG classes with some methods for the all I have mentioned method  dependency so I wanted to use both classes but in fortunately execution order is not correct so that is issue

Comment: Now I am able to use it just need to specify the complete class path like I have used  '@Test(dependsOnMethods="Tests.Profile.PrivacySettings.PrivacySettingsModule.updatePrivacySettingForParticipantWithGuide",alwaysRun=true)'

Comment: Murali kindly look to issue that I have reported ...maybe you will provide better solution for this  http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17270/test-methods-executed-which-is-are-mentioned-in-test-suite-xml

Comment: posted answer there..please try once. thank you